# Sublime Text Custom Build source.less not working

Tags: node.js, less, sublimetext3

I'm trying to create an script for compiling LESS running via Sublime Text Build Systems.

This is the content of my `LESS.sublime-build` file:

```
{
    "cmd": [ "node", "${packages}/buildLessWithLessDrama/buildLessWithLessDrama.js", "$file","$file_name","$file_path" ],
    "selector": "source.less"
}
```

It works perfectly if I choose `Tools -> Build System -> LESS`. But it doesn't in "Automatic" mode.
Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Are you sure that the file you're editing is using `LESS` as the syntax highlighting language when you try to build?

Comment: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html: Build systems can be run by pressing F7 (which is the shortcut for Build) or from Tools | Build. What is your "automatic" mode? You can create a marcro (http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html) which saves, build (and so compile) your code.